# Official Typescript support for Highcharts

Tags: typescript, highcharts, typescript-typings

Is there an official official Typescript support for Highcharts? Community created https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/highcharts doesn't fully map to the latest Highcharts JS. I assume there must be at least initiative from Highsoft to support typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is **no** but Highcharts team is currently working on this.

You follow the progress here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4876

Answer (score 0):

With the latest release of Highcharts v7.0.0 they have added support for TypeScript but its still in Beta phase.

Also its became heavy bundle with all these.